# Texto “caracteres da tag” na “Como fazer uma tag” está quebrado

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização, tags, interface-usuario

Quando uma pergunta é feita, ao lado da caixa de edição de tags, aparece um texto de ajuda “Como fazer uma tag”. Neste texto, há

> caracteres da tag: [a a z 0 a 9 + # - .]

Algo está errado. Deveria ser algo como:

> caracteres da tag: a–z áâãàçéêíóôõú 0–9 -+.#

ou

> caracteres da tag: letras dígitos -+.#

[image: screenshot]

---

(English version because my Portuguese may not be comprehensible, feel free to edit)

When asking a question, next to the tag edit box, a help text appears: “Como fazer uma tag”. In this text, there is

> caracteres da tag: [a a z 0 a 9 + # - .]

Something is wrong. This should be something like

> caracteres da tag: a-z áâãàçéêíóôõú 0-9 -+#.

or

> caracteres da tag: letras dígitos -+.#

Comment: This looks like a UI oversight from when we enabled non-ASCII tags; I will have to see if I can think of some terse yet accurate way of describing what *is* allowed! Out of curiosity, can I assume that the middle "a" here in  "a a z", "0 a 9" can be interpreted as (in English) "to"?

Comment: @MarcGravell Oh, that's what it means! (I don't speak Portuguese, I only guess it from French...) I think “letters” (“letras”?) would work best, same as http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/589/how-to-tag-character-list-omits-accented-letters

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, you are right: "a to z" and "0 to 9".

Comment: @MarcGravell it can be interpreted that way, but it looks weird. Also, speaking for myself, when I see something that says I can use a-z, I automatically assume I can use all the accents. We don't thing of accented chars as *different letters* in Portuguese. They're the same thing, just spoken in a different way. Another pt-speaking soul might have a different take on the subject, though.

Comment: @Gabe Oh? Maybe it's my programming background, but when I see a-z, I assume ASCII only. (I'm French, so my outlook on accented letters should be pretty much the same as in Portuguese.)

Comment: @Gilles Yeah, my programming background tells me the same thing, but I still don't thing I'd do this in this particular case (because I'm not looking at a regex, or something within a programming context). This is a site full of programmers, though, so it'd be nice to have some more opinions on the subject

Comment: @Gabe in that case - with your "We don't thing of accented chars as different letters in Portuguese" - is it already correct as written?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, but I'd change the "a a z 0 a 9" to something like "a até z, 0 até 9"

Comment: @Gabe see also the [discussion on French](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/589/how-to-tag-character-list-omits-accented-letters?noredirect=1#comment1144_589); the list is much wider than that really

Comment: @Gabe the a vs até is down to our translators; we can try to sidestep, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be clearer next build, although there will be some period where it shows in English while it goes via our 3rd-party translation service.

Comment: New version is definitely better